# Receiving user input and storing it in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I cannot for the life of me figure out why my code isn't producing the output I need. The requirement is to not use any functions. When I input a line of text like "text", the resulting array is "tex" cutting off the last letter which makes no sense to me.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int read_input( char line_of_text[] )
{
        int index = 0;
        char ch;
//      if(!line_of_text[0])
//              return index;
        for(ch = getchar(); ch != '\n' && ch != '\0'; ch = getchar()){
                if(ch == EOF){ //clear string and return EOF
                        line_of_text[0] = '\0';
                        return EOF;
                }
                line_of_text[index++] = ch;

        }
        line_of_text[++index] = '\0';
        return index;
}
```

Comment: `char ch;` --> `int ch = 0;`

Comment: `line_of_text[++index] = '\0';` -> `line_of_text[index] = '\0';`

Comment: why do you clear the string when reach EOF?

Comment: I was also curious about that

Comment: BTW your code kinda works, [here](https://ideone.com/qJmPBt). How do you allocate memory in your actual code and how do you think to avoid buffer overflows?

Comment: what do you mean by: `requirement is to not use any functions`?  the posted code is a function: `read_input()`  and twice it calls function: `getchar()`   Perhaps you meant: `requirement is to not use any string functions`.  If that is true, then why the `#include <string.h>` ?  Please clarify.

Comment: when indenting code, do not use tabs.  Because each wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts and allows for many indent levels across the page.

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humams: separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line

Comment: the `read_input()` functions needs an additional parameter that will contain the max length of the array pointed to by the `line_of_text[]` parameter.

Comment: It was very suspiciously close to function and that's what made it so frustrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after applying all the comments and cleaning up the logic

Notice how the vertical and horizontal spacing make the code much easier to read/understand

Notice the statements do not use any 'side effects' to handle increment of 'index' variable

```
int read_input( int max_chars, char line_of_text[] )
{
    int index = 0;
    int ch = 0; // getchar() returns an int, not a char

    // Note: initialization of 'index' handled in declaration
    // Note: '-1' to leave room for NUL termination char
    for( ; index < (max_chars-1); index++ )
    {
        ch = getchar();

        // Note: place literal on left so compiler can catch  `=` error
        if( EOF == ch || '\n' == ch || '\0' == ch )
        {
            break;
        }

        // acceptable char so place into buffer
        line_of_text[index] = ch;
    }

    // when done, terminate the char string
    line_of_text[index] = '\0';

    return index;
} // end function: read_input
```

Comment: Thank you I think it was the char instead of an int that was messing things up!!